# Getting an "Error while reading the sourcefile!" error from Jenkins jacoco plugin

Tags: jenkins, sbt, jacoco

My source code is written in scala. I have used sbt-jacoco sbt plugin of version 3.0.3 for code coverage. Jenkins plugin used is JaCoCo Plugin of version 3.0.1

I have implemented jacoco within my Jenkinsfile as :

```
step([$class: 'JacocoPublisher', sourcePattern: '**/src'])
```

The plugin works perfectly fine , shows the code percentages covered and missed. But when I go to check the actual lines of code covered through the Jenkins UI, I get the above error *"Error while reading the sourcefile!"*
Would you help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Attached screenshots

[image: error page]

Answer (score 10):

look at jenkins log (usually at `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`) for exceptions like `java.io.FileNotFoundException` to figure out where the plugin think the file located at, or any other errors while trying to read the file.

what solve it for me was setting the sourcePattern to `'**/src/*/java'` 
which by default it is set to `'**/src/main/java'`
[based on git](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/jacoco/JacocoPublisher.java#L116)